# Grails - how to load .properties file after deploying WAR file

Tags: grails, properties, war

So I am loading the app.properties file using grails.config.locations = ["file:${basedir}/web-app/WEB-INF/app.properties"]

But when I deploy by creating a WAR file, it has a different directory structure, where the app.properties file is under WEB-INF/app.properties, and it can't find the file.

For one, ${basedir} is not defined when running WAR file, and second, path is not the same.
I've tried changing the paths and also removed ${basedir}, etc. Does anyone know how to source a properties file that would work while running grails and also when deployed as WAR file?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341117/is-it-possible-that-grails-xxconfig-groovy-as-a-script-no-compile

```
//Config.groovy
grails.config.locations =
["file:shared/TZLibConfig.groovy"]

//BuildConfig.groovy
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    copy(todir: "${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/shared"){
        fileset(dir:"shared",includes:"**")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of possible approaches:

You could  make sure the property file is in the classpath of the running JVM.  You can add to the classpath on the command line by java -Dclasspath=/path/to/property/file:$CLASSPATH

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(propsName);
    props.load(url.openStream());
    return props;
```

You could specify the location as an absolute value in an environment variable (System.getenv('FILELOCATION'))